# Regex find proper case and exclude some word in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have some text like this:

> After a lifetime in the French diplomatic corps, the Count de Gruse
>   lived with his wife in an elegant townhouse on Quai Voltaire. He was a
>   likeable man, cultivated of course, with a well-deserved reputation as
>   a generous host and an amusing raconteur.

I want to find all Proper case by using regex find. My exclude is the proper case after the dot like

```
. He
```

I have search on internet and found this input can  me

```
[a-z] [A-Z][\w]*
```

Rhe problem is you can mark Quai not all 2 or 3 words like Quai Voltaire and how can I exclude some proper case like I, Me, My ...?

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed *after* it was answered. I had no trouble understanding it, although it's not native English. I'll try editing it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Andreas. Now, if this is a one-time task you can break down into multiple steps, I'd suggest temporarily excluding the exceptions first, probably using an otherwise-unused character, and then putting it back later. Here is a Find, and a Replace:

```
\b(I|God|Dad)\b
@\1
```

That gives us something like this (note that me and my are not capitalized in English):

```
Did @I write this to @God, @Dad, or my wife? After a lifetime in the 
French diplomatic corps, the Count de Gruse lived with his wife 
in an elegant townhouse on Quai Voltaire! He was a likeable man, 
cultivated of course, with a well-deserved reputation as a 
generous host and an amusing raconteur.
```

From there, you can use a *case-sensitive* regex and negative-lookbehind to find capitalized words preceded by one or more spaces not following a sentence boundary:

```
 (?<![.?'!"])[ ]+[A-Z]
```

Note that this will fail for hard-wrapped text, such as 'French' in the example as I showed it above.

Regex can be rather brittle, so something like this may require a small program/script if it's not a one-time task. (Or maybe possibly a macro.)

Having said that, here is what you asked for, incorporating negative lookahead too so as to do it all in one step. :)

```
(?<![.?'!"]) (?!Dad\b|God\b|I\b)[A-Z]
```

TIP: if you don't have or don't prefer to use the case-sensitive checkbox, you can put this at the front of the regex:

```
(?c)
```

Comment: You're welcome--glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions and complex exceptions does not blend very well.  *perl* comes very quickly to mind when it comes to [natural language processing](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=636511).

Answer (score 0):

When i add

```
[\w]*
```

then my regex is

```
(?<![.?'!"]) (?!Dad\b|God\b|I\b)[A-Z][\w]*
```

It works perfectly